# SSIS web service script task wsdl file

Tags: web-services, ssis, wsdl

I am working on a SSIS package where we have to call or consume a web service in SSIS through Script task. I have gone through so many links but I am not able to find the exact solution.

My requirement is I already have a WSDL file . We need to consume that WSDL file and we need to identify the methods inside this WSDL and need to write the data available in this WSDL to the data base tables.  how can we read the WSDL file and how we can load the data into DB table.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This can be done utilizing python and a module called [Zeep](http://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/) I have added a method to insert the results from that API call to the backend but if you run as is it should return the method calls in your WSDL file. You will just need to create a table that accepts the varchar values in this case called "WSDLMethods".

```
import operator
import pypyodbc
from zeep import Client

dbUser = ''
dbPass = ''
mydatabase = ''
myserver = ''

methodlist = []
wsdl = 'https://ws.cdyne.com/delayedstockquote/delayedstockquote.asmx?wsdl'
client = Client(wsdl=wsdl)
for service in client.wsdl.services.values():
    print ("service:", service.name)
    for port in service.ports.values():
        operations = sorted(
            port.binding._operations.values(),
            key=operator.attrgetter('name'))
        for operation in operations:
            methodlist.append(operation.name)

#remove duplicates from list
methodlist = list(set(methodlist))

def insertToDB(methodName):
    connection = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};Server='+myserver+';Database=' +str(mydatabase) +';uid='+ str(dbUser)+';pwd=' + str(dbPass)+'')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    SQLCommand = (" INSERT INTO WSDLMethods VALUES('" + str(methodName) + "')")
    print(SQLCommand)
    cursor.execute(SQLCommand)
    cursor.close()
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()

for method in methodlist:
    #insertToDB(method)
    print(method)
```